# C# MVC Model is always valid when Unit Testing a Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I am very beginner in this C# world.

There is this model class:

```
    public class Fund
    {
        [Required]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string nickname { get; set; }
    }
```

Although the `[Required]` annotation is over all properties, an instance like:

```
Fund f = new Fund();
f.name = "test name";
f.nickname = "test ninckname";
```

always pass in a test like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

How am I supposed to set the model such that an instance like that won't pass in in the `ModelState.IsValid` test?

Other instances like:

```
Fund f1 = new Fund();
f1.id = 3;
f1.nickname = "test ninckname";
```

and

```
Fund f2 = new Fund();
f2.id = 3;
f2.name = "test name";
```

are also passing on the test.

**EDIT:**

The `ModelState.IsValid` is inside a controller, I am testing the controller actually.

**EDIT 2:**

That is the controller's method signature:

```
[HttpPatch]
public ActionResult EditFund(Fund fund)
```

**EDIT 3:**
That is my whole test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEditInvalidFund()
{
    // Arrange
    FundController controller = new FundController();
    controller.ControllerContext = TestModelHelper.AdminControllerContext();
    var _fund = new Mock<IFund>();
    _fund.SetupGet(f => f.id).Returns(1);
    //_fund.SetupGet(f => f.name).Returns("Fund name");
    _fund.SetupGet(f => f.nickname).Returns("Fund nickname");
    _fund.Setup(f => f.Edit()).Callback(() => {}).Verifiable();

    // Act
    var result = (JsonResult)controller.EditFund(_fund.Object);

    // Assert
    SimpleMessage resultMessage = m_serializer.Deserialize<SimpleMessage>(m_serializer.Serialize(result.Data));
    Assert.IsNotNull(resultMessage.status, "JSON record does not contain 'status' required property.");
    Assert.IsTrue(resultMessage.status.Equals("fail"), "status must be 'fail'");
}
```

And that is the whole controller's method:

```
[HttpPatch]
public ActionResult EditFund(IFund _fund)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //_fund.Edit();
        }
        else
        {
            string error_messages = "";
            foreach (var e in ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count > 0).ToList())
            {
                error_messages += e[0].ErrorMessage + "\n";
            }
            throw new Exception(error_messages);
        }
        return MessageHelper(@Resources.Global.success, @Resources.Funds.success_editing_fund, "success");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        return ErrorHelper(@Resources.Global.error, @Resources.Funds.error_editing_fund, err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you think the 1st example is not valid - you have provided values for ``name ` and `nickname` and the default for `int` is `0` which is also valid. If you want it to be invalid for the int, make it nullable and add the `[Required]` attribute

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll, yes it is inside a controller, sorry about that, just edited.

Comment: Your code snippets are from a Controller, and you're trying to unit test?

Comment: You need to show the signature of the method - if the method has a parameter for the model, then the 2nd and 3rd will be invalid.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, well, it is not that I think it shouldn't be valid. I am actually looking for a way to verify that all properties are set properly, is there any?

Comment: It could be that the string values are passing the required validation because they are Empty rather than null. Try setting the "AllowEmptyString" to false on your Required attribute

Comment: No, it's because Model Validation happens in the ModelBinding step before your controller action is even called. So you have to fake that step in your unit test before calling the Action.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll, how can I do that?

Comment: That's what the extension method on github that I referenced in my answer does :-)

Comment: But actually it's 1 line:  controller.ModelState.AddModelError("FieldName", @"error message")

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll allright, I'll give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unit test `ModelState.IsValid`. Well, you can, but you need extra code to do it, and it's not exactly ideal.

Here's my code on github: [`WithModelStateIsInvalid<TController>()`](https://github.com/chrisfcarroll/TestBase/blob/master/TestBase-Mvc/MvcExtensions.cs)

And here's the NuGet package it's in: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TestBase-Mvc/

And here's how I use it:

```
UnitUnderTest
    .WithModelStateIsInValid()
    .Action(model)
    .ShouldBeViewResult()
    .ShouldBeAnInvalidModel();
```

—————————————————————————————————————————

The reason you can't unit test it, is that Model Validation happens in the ModelBinding step **before** your controller action is called.

So to simulate a model validation failure, the easiest way is to invalidate `controller.ModelState` 'manually' in your unit test code, before calling the action. Which is what the extension method does, but actually it's just one-line:

```
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("FieldName", @"error message")
```

*(A more sophisticated extension method would probably let you specify which Model key is invalid. PRs always welcome).*

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! About your code on GitHub, it is very advanced, I can't understand, but I'll keep it for when I get smarter.

Comment: :-) Ta. One day I'll simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Required]
public int id { get; set; }
```

This will always be valid since an int is not nullable. It has a default value of 0.

Comment: I see, but how about the other properties like `name` and `nickname`?

Comment: @ThiagoMelo strings are nullable types, so you have to specify a value for those for the [Required] attribute to pass.

Comment: could you provide a small snippet? how should can I specify a value for them?

Comment: @ThiagoMelo if you leave them as null, they will fail the Required check. You can't fail the Required check for an int unless you are passing in a json or XML request or something like that and the caller leaves that out completely.

Comment: well, I have this controller's method, which is used for update the model. I am intending to create a unit test for check whether the method allows an invalid model instance to be written in the database, do you know how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why it gets valid, but you can try to explicitly revalidate the model by:

```
TryValidateModel(fund)
```